# Set Ubuntu 12.04 Dash's default lens to its application lens and some other tweaks!

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

Here are the questions about persistent dash customization for my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

1. Assign the *Application Lens* as the default lens selected when the dash is called with <kbd>Super</kbd> or other assigned key OR, assign a different lens as my dash home;
2. Show the *full list of the installed applications* as in the snapshot below (I am looking for a customization where full app list would be the default);
3. The *Filter results* should too come up pre-selected with the dash.

[image: snap1]

Comment: You can Set via `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Dash scopes <your order>` where you can select as you want in `<your order>`. To get **current** setting, run `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Dash scopes`.

Comment: @Pandya the value set for `com.canonical.Unity.Dash`'s only key (in my 12.04 system) `home-lens-ordering` is `['applications.lens', 'files.lens', 'music.lens']`.. yes app-lens is the first, but still it's not the default that shows up when I call the dash with Super..

Answer (score 4):

This is quite a hacky answer.

I would suggest you assign this script to another key, such as a function key. I went for F3 because it doesn't do much in any applications I use.

You need to install xdotool:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

First run the commands

```
touch .dashopen
gedit .dashopen
```

and write into it

> closed

And the commands

```
touch .filteropen
```

Now you need to create a cron job. Run:

```
crontab -e
```

and into it, write

> @reboot echo 'closed' > .filteropen

then do

```
touch dasha.sh
gedit dasha.sh
```

into that you need to put the following:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

#DASHOPEN

# get the state of the dash.
do=$(<.dashopen)
fo=$(<.filteropen)

# if it is closed:
if [ $do = 'closed' ]; then
    # open the applications pane
    xdotool key super+a
    # and record that it is open
    echo 'open' > .dashopen
# if it is open
else
    # close it with the super key
    xdotool key super
    # record that it is closed
    echo 'closed' > .dashopen
fi

#FILTEROPEN

# if it is closed:
if [ $fo = 'closed' ]; then
    # get the mouse location
    eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
    # move to the filter button and click
    xdotool mousemove 1000 60 # CHANGE THIS LINE TO WORK ON YOUR SCREEN.
    # click after 1 second
    sleep 1 && xdotool click 1
    # and record that it is open
    echo 'open' > .filteropen
    # move back to original location
    xdotool mousemove $X $Y
fi
```

make it executable:

```bsh
chmod +x dasha.sh
```

Now you need to add the keyboard shortcut:

Open system settings, and click keyboard.

[image]

Click Shortcuts, then custom shortcuts.

[image]

Click `[+]` then type the following:

> Dash Application
>
> ./dasha.sh

[image]

Click disabled and press your chosen shortcut key:

[image]

<sub>Please comment if I've made a mistake</sub>

Comment: Isn't your script just a new way of opening _Dash_?

Comment: it's not exactly the one..

Comment: @LittleByBlue My script opens the application pane by default using the keyboard shortcut Super+A.

Comment: @rusty I have done quite a bit of research and can't see another way...

Comment: Not sure if this would be easier. Get xdotool, use the xtool command in your script, set custom keybind as Super, use ccsm (CompizConfigSettingsManager) to change launcher open to different binding (mines Super F). Not sure about how this is expanding the "Full List of Installed.." and filter, but I think they edited post. I can't test this right now, as my apt-get is not working all of a sudden

Comment: @Notime, can't set a custom keybind as Super with xbindkeys... and ccsm doesn't let me change off super, although it should.

Comment: @NoTime the post was edited prior to any answers was posted, and nothing much has changed actually.. you can see the revisions here http://askubuntu.com/posts/488838/revisions

Comment: @rusty it won't expand, but if it was already open it will stay open... You have to open it onece per login

Comment: Yeah that's okay... I have been thinking about the mouse move thing but it would depend on screen size... I'll add in the basics later today that you can adjust...

Comment: @rusty I have changed it, it now opens the filter tab.